# replace data in hive table with zero downtime

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata

I receive tab-delimited data periodically and load it into hive tables.

I need a way to re-load the table when I get a new dataset, with zero downtime.  This won't work:

```
drop table t;
load data local inpath ... into table t;   // table is down while loading
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need a staging table, tons of solutions are available, this may be interesting

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141530/when-you-switch-table-a-to-table-b-does-the-index-data-get-switched-as-well

you may also consider switching between two online tables using a view
so table t will become:

Tablet TFlip

Table TFlop

view VT --Select * from TFlip

when loading data you can

```
load data local inpath ... into table TFlop;   // view remain up while loading
```

and at the end

```
alter view VT as Select * from TFlop GO
```

in the next load you'll do the oposite by loading into table TFlip and then updating the view to point to TFlip

Comment: I'm not familiar with hive so this is not the complete solution just a potential approach to your problem ( by the way I updated the alter view script )